# Test whether $f(x)=x+1/x$ is contraction or not

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

> Define $f:[2,\infty)\to [2,\infty)$ by $f(x)=x+\frac 1x$. Test whether $f$ is a contraction map or not.

It is clear that $f$ has no fixed point in $[2,\infty)$ and since $[2,\infty)$ is complete so by Banach contraction principle $f$ is NOT a contraction map.

But, I want to show by definition that $f$ is not a contraction map.

We have, $|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y|.|1-\frac 1{xy}|$ for all $x,y \ge 2$. Now I have to estimate $|1-\frac 1{xy}|$. Since $x,y \ge 2$, so $|1-\frac 1{xy}|\ge \frac 34. $ But that does not conclude anything !

Any hint. please ?

Comment: Is there a fixed $0<q<1$ such that $\left| {1 - \frac{1}{{xy}}} \right| < q$ for all $x,y\geq 2$?

Comment: yeah, that is the question actually.

Comment: Think about what happens when $x$ and/or $y$ becomes very large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there exist $c <1$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq c |x-y|$ for all $x,y$. Put $x=n, y=n+1$ to get $|1+\frac1  {n+1}-\frac 1 n | \leq c$. You get a  contradiction by letting $n \to \infty$.